# How do I rename multiple files beginning with a Unix timestamp - imapsync issue

Tags: linux, timestamp, imap, synchronization

I didn't got the script from `imapsync` to rename maildir filenames to work. :-/

So what I need is:

I have a mail folder with thousands of mails. After importing those emails to my new server, the filename of the emails got the creation date as a `Unix` timestamp in the filename, but the creation date flag of the file is the correct receive date from the email.

ls -l for one file looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 popuser popuser  1350432 2013-03-16 07:22 1363563215.M562903P29332V0000000000000802I0000000000AEA46B_527.my-domain.org,S=1350432:2,S
```

So what the script has to do is: 
1) read the creation date/time of the file (I found the command

```
stat -c %y filename
```

does this)

2) convert the date/time from 1) to a Unix timestamp

```
date -d "2013-03-17 11:19:01.000000000 +0100" "+%s"
```

3) delete the first 10 digits (wrong timestamp) of the filename and us the the timestamp from 2) instead

4) do this for all files in a specific directory

I'm a newby in `Linux` scripts, can anyone help me with this script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this with [`rename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/rename) :

```
$ rename -n 's/^\d+/(stat($_))[9]/e' [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
```

from the `shell` prompt. It's very useful, you can put some [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) code like I does in a substitution for [`stat`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) with the `e` modifier.
You can remove the `-n` (dry-run mode switch) when your tests become valids.

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

---

### Edit

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468028/how-do-i-rename-multiple-files-beginning-with-a-unix-timestamp-imapsync-issue/15468123?noredirect=1#comment21904887_15468123), if you have the following error :

> Argument list too long

Then use `find` like this :

```
find -type f -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*' -print0|
    xargs -0 -n1 rename -n 's/^\d+/(stat($_))[9]/e'
```

(try it without `-n1`, that should works too)

Comment: thx for this great answer! It worked with a test directory where I have 500 files. 

I've only one issue left, the directory has 13 Mio. files... it looks like that's too much for this :-( is there a way to solve this issue easily? 

Error Message: -bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'too much for this', have you tried it ? Do you have any error ? Is your PC get inflamed ? Tell us.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, as I wrote in my last post. The error message from my ubuntu 10.04 machine was: "-bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long" with less files in the directory it worked.