# How to move and number files?

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, move, cat

I working with linux, bash.

I have one directory with **100** folders in it, each one named different.

In each of these 100 folders, there is a file called first.bars (so I have 100 files named **first.bars**). Although all named first.bars, the files are actually slightly different.

I want to get all these files moved to one new folder and rename/number these files so that I know which file comes from which folder. So the first **first.bars** file must be renamed to **001.bars**, the second to **002.bars**.. etc.

I have tried the following:

```
ls -d * >> /home/directorywiththe100folders/list.txt
cat list.txt | while read line;
do cd $line;
mv first.bars /home/newfolder
```

This does not work because I can't have 100 files, named the same, in one folder. So I only need to know how to rename them. The renaming must be connected to the cat list.txt, because the first line is the folder containing the first file wich is moved and renamed. That file will be called 001.bars.

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this :

```
$ rename 's/^.*?\./sprintf("%03d.", $c++)/e' *.bar
```

If you want more information about this command, see this recent response I gave earlier : [How do I rename multiple files beginning with a Unix timestamp - imapsync issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468028/how-do-i-rename-multiple-files-beginning-with-a-unix-timestamp-imapsync-issue/15468123?noredirect=1#comment21902638_15468123)

Comment: I can't get this to work. I first tried it incorporating it in my own code, but that doesn't work. Then I tried it in a single folder (one of those 100) and tried to rename the first.bar file with your code. Unfortunately, nothing happens. Rename asks me to give 3 inputs: from, to and file. *.bar is obviously the file, but I think he doesn't recognize the from and to.

Comment: @rubano : I over guess that **you don't have read my link** ! Especially the **note** part.

Comment: I actually read your link, but it didn't help (at first). But I eventually did get it to work. Thank you very much Sputnick!

Answer (score 0):

If the `rename` command is not available,

```
for d in /home/directorywiththe100folders/*/; do
    newfile=$(printf "/home/newfolder/%d.bars" $(( c++ )) )
    mv "$d/first.bars" "$newfile"
done
```