# Bash how can rename a file saved into a variable?

Tags: bash, copy, file-rename

how can I do this:

I have a file, `eval.txt` saved into a variable, that I want to rename `timestamp_eval.txt`

```
filetosend=/home/cft/eval.txt
filename=$(echo $filetosend | cut -d '/' -f4) //to get only the name
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
filename=${DATE}_${filename} //add timestamp to name
```

how can I rename `$filetosend` ?

I found this solution:

```
DATE=(date +%Y%m%d)
mydir=$(echo $(dirname $a))
myfile=$(echo $(basename $a))
myfile=${DATE}_${myfile}
filetosend=$mydir/$myfile
cp $a $filetosend
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this *if you really need a **variable*** :

```
filetosend=/home/cft/eval.txt
cd "${filetosend%/*}"
filename="${filetosend##*/}"
DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
filename="${DATE}_$filename"
mv "$filetosend" "$filename"
```

If *you don't really need a **variable*** using `rename` :

```
rename "s|[^/]+$|$(date +%Y%m%d)_$&|" /home/cft/eval.txt
```

or decomposed on multi-lines :

```
cd /home/cft/
rename "s/.*/$(date "+%Y%m%d")_$&/" eval.txt
rename "s|[^/]+$|$(date "+%Y%m%d")_$&|"
```

### Note

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15468123/465183) to know if you have the good `rename` on your system + extra explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to do:

```
mv /home/cft/eval.txt /home/cft/$(date "+%Y%m%d")_eval.txt
```

Comment: Hi sudo_O, Read again the title sudo_O : "Bash how can rename a file saved into a **variable**?" =)

Comment: But maybe you have psychics skills and it's the good response =D

Comment: Hi @sputnick, Read again my answers sputnick : "The simplest way would be to do ..." =) Benubird answer already shows the `mv` command needed to finish the OPs script. I simply show that this can be achieved without the need of variables. Might be useful to take a step back and not over complicate a simple task.

Answer (score -2):

Using the mv command. "mv" is short for "move".

```
mv $filetosend $filename
```

Comment: You should note that the new file `$filename` will end up in the directory that the script is run from and not `/home/cft/` *(unless of course that is where the script is run from)*. You might want to use the aboslute path instead `mv "$filetosend" "/home/cft/$filename"`.