# sed removing spaces before and after something

Tags: sed, awk, rename

I'm wondering how to make mass rename (using rename or sed/awk), for files like this:

```
Name 1 - Name 2 - Name 3.doc
Name 1- Name 2 - Name 3.doc
Name 1 -Name 2 - Name 3.doc
```

the problem is that i want to have all files in the same schema, for example

`Name 1-Name 2-Name 3.doc`

without spaces at all. I'm reading rename documentation but can't find way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
rename 's/\s*-\s*/-/g' *.doc
```

You need the Perl's `rename`, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15468123/465183)

Comment: Works fine, thanks man, only one problem is it deletes spaces only before and after first '-', not the second one. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
for file in *.doc; do 
   mv "$file" "$(sed 's# *- *#-#g' <<< "$file")"
done
```

Comment: but it removes all spaces, and i need to remove only spaces before and after '-', is it possible at all by one action?